# Android Studoi does not launch

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded and installed Android Studio today, however after the successful installation, it didnt launch, instead I get the following error message, please advice.

NB: My computer satisfies the minimum requirements.

The error:

---

Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Unable to create Channel from class class io.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioServerSocketChannel
    at io.netty.channel.ReflectiveChannelFactory.newChannel(ReflectiveChannelFactory.java:40)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:316)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.doBind(AbstractBootstrap.java:281)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:277)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:266)
    at org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer.bind(BuiltInServer.java:152)
    at org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer.start(BuiltInServer.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer.startNioOrOio(BuiltInServer.java:107)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:154)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:128)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.underLocks(SocketLock.java:191)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:128)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:318)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:140)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to set the server socket timeout.
    at io.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioServerSocketChannel.(OioServerSocketChannel.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioServerSocketChannel.(OioServerSocketChannel.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.ReflectiveChannelFactory.newChannel(ReflectiveChannelFactory.java:38)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:307)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.setSoTimeout(ServerSocket.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioServerSocketChannel.(OioServerSocketChannel.java:81)

### ... 27 more

Rgds,
OMAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this as a resolution for a different error but it worked for me.
1- Open CMD
2- Type and run: netsh winsock reset

OMAS